# Using RegExp in sql to find rows that only contain 'x'

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do i use a regexp to only find rows where the first name only includes one type of character 'x' but it doesnt matter how many characters there are.

So far I came up with:

```
 REGEXP_LIKE(LOWER(fst_name),'^x+$'))
```

possible rows I am looking for:

'x'

'xx'

'xxx'

'xxxxxxxxx'

So im interpreting this as meaning find the rows where x is at the beginning and the end of the field and there can be only x's inbetween. Am I interpreting this correctly?

or is it possible to have: 'xxxxxxaxxxxx'

Comment: Can you edit your question to describe the strings that you are looking for a litle bit? Currently it sounds like you should use the 'like' function in sql. fst_name like '%x%'

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with SQL regexes, but in theory your regex `'^x+$'`looks correct. It reads something like "Match strings that consist solely of 1 or more `x`"

Comment: i can't use the % operator because then I would be matching characters other than 'x'. I want to query rows that only contain 1 or more x's and nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is correct:

```
^x+$
```

- `^` is the "start" anchor
- `x` is the character for which you are searching. I assume it isn't a regex metacharacter
- `+` is the "one or more" quantifier
- `$` is the "end" anchor

So I would interpret your regex to match all of the cases you supplied, and would *not* match something like 'xxxxaxxxx'. http://regex101.com/r/dE8vU6

It's been long enough since I used Oracle that I don't recall whether your REGEX_LIKE syntax is correct there, but it seems right to me.